# Visual Studio Shell And F# (invalid license)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, f#, visual-studio-shell

Does anyone have any experience with installing the **Visual Studio Isolated Shell** and using it with ***F#***?

It installed successfully, but when I click on the **devenv.exe**, it opens VS, but gives me the error *"Invalid License Data. Reinstall is required"*. I have done that many times to no avail.

Googling for this issue, I find that **devenv.exe** is not supposed to work in this isolated mode directly, but rather, I should have another custom executable that targets the VS Shell. This seems to be true for **IronPython** **Studio** which I downloaded and works fine.

However, I cannot believe there isn't anything similar for ***F#***. Any input in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# requires the VS *Integrated* Shell.

See also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196765/what-is-the-minimum-list-of-tools-required-to-work-on-f-does-express-edition-wo